# CSP errors with the Angular nvd3 package

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, content-security-policy

I'm using the [angular d3 package](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) to place charts into my app and am getting the error shown at the bottom:

A couple things that did not yield results:

- Setting a nonce on the content security policy of the server response header as script-src 'self' nonce-nRfqpuKWNuYyUAFPTr6WVNZk9 and passing it in as nonce="nRfqpuKWNuYyUAFPTr6WVNZk9" on the script tag of the nvd3 javascript package import which I am hosting. See [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/10/04/csp-for-the-web-we-have/)
- Setting a nonce on the content security policy of the header as style-src nonce-nRfqpuKWNuYyUAFPTr6WVNZk9 and passing it in to the associated nvd3 stylesheet import
- Including the ngCsp package and importing the angular-csp.css per the angular docs

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

```
nv.d3.min.js:3 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
> nonce-nRfqpuKWNuYyUAFPTr6WVNZk9". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword,
> a hash ('sha256-Sd940mhg11baB1cb1LWCO1WC3mgZyv2jlD9Z3wJqMoQ='), or a
> nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. (anonymous
> function)  
>@ nv.d3.min.js:3a.dom.write  
>@ nv.d3.min.js:3c 
>@ nv.d3.min.js:3(anonymous function)  
>@ nv.d3.min.js:6t  
>@ d3.min.js:1m 
>@ nv.d3.min.js:3(anonymous function)  
>@ d3.min.js:1
```